# Compiler Construction Overlapping First Sets

Tags: compiler-construction, context-free-grammar

I am attempting to create a compiler and have calculated the first sets but have run into the following problem.

```
LHS -> Var
LHS -> Field
```

Where Var and Field are nonterminals with overlapping first sets thus making the grammer ambiguous. I was wondering if there is an way to solve this problem.

Comment: Usually, things like variable and field names are parsed simply as *identifiers* and bound to the correct symbol/declaration later during semantic analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Ambiguous" means there are two or more possible parses. That's probably not the case with your grammar. Overlapping FIRST sets indicates that a top-down parser isn't capable of guessing the correct parse. That doesn't mean that there isn't one. A bottom-up parser may well just work.

If you insist on too-down parsing, you'll need to modify your grammar. There are standard heuristics, although nothing is guaranteed to work and it may simply be impossible. Often, you will find that *left-factoring* is sufficient. You may also need to *eliminate left-recursion*. You'll find algorithms for both of these in your textbook (if you have one), on Wikipedia, and all over the internet. (Of course, not all of the algorithms you'll find on the internet are correct, bug-free, and well-explained.)

Comment: I would prefer to use top down for reasons I won't get into and I think left factorizing is the way to go I just can't seem to figure out how to do it in this scenario as Var and Field have the same prefix (actually Var is fields prefix) and Field is longer.

Comment: @NullPointer7: then you'll have to modify your grammar to eliminate `Field` and replace it with the left factored version (`Var FieldSuffix`). That's what left-factoring means: factoring out shared prefixes

Comment: Would you be able to left factorise this grammer as LHS does not have a common prefix

Comment: @NullPointer7: you left-factor the right-hand side; the left-hand side is always a single non-terminal. Or, more accurately, you left-factor a grammar, since it is almost never just one production. In this case, as I said, you need to refactor the `Field` production itself, so as to make the fact that it starts with `Var`.

Comment: I will try that thank you, just being cautious as I need to print the parsed tree from this for my university assignment but thank you for the help.